# Replace list number values with others?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []

for number in start_list:
    number = number**2
    #I bet something should be added here but 
    #I have no idea what that would be
square_list.append(start_list[0])
square_list.append(start_list[1])
square_list.append(start_list[2])
square_list.append(start_list[3])
square_list.append(start_list[4])
square_list.sort()

print square_list
```

and I actually want to create a new list (the square_list) which includes the numbers of the start_list squared and sorted. This is my first day on python so be gentle!

Answer (score 4):

Build a generator over the list producing your result, and feed it to `sorted` to get a list based on ascending value, eg:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]

square_list = sorted(n**2 for n in start_list)
# [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Answer (score 1):

as I understand In your case  it should looks like this:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []

for number in start_list:
    number = number**2
    square_list.append(number)
square_list.sort()
```

but You can use other methods

```
square_list = sorted(number**2 for number in start_list)
```

or

```
square_list = [number**2 for number in start_list]
square_list.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon Clements' generator approach is the best and most pythonic way of doing this, however I think since you're a beginner it's worth understanding the `for` loop way of doing it. You've clearly understood the elements you need, you just need to plug them together in a new way.

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []

for number in start_list:
```

All good so far, but you want to be adding these to `square_list` instead of doing `number = number**2`. Your code is simply modifying a temporary variable, rather than changing anything in place, assigning a new value to `number` won't change `start_list`. You want to this next:

```
  square_list.append(number**2)
```

Then you just need to sort and print as you've already done

```
square_list.sort()
print(square_list)
```

(`print` without the brackets will work but it's being dropped with Python 3 so it's best to get used to using brackets now)

Comment: Glad to help. The convention round here is to upvote answers that help you rather than leaving a comment, though. Click the grey uparrow next to my answer (and any others you like) to do that. You can also click the tick next to the answer you think is best to accept it as an answer to your question.